# Jquery toggle not acting as expected. trying to toggle sections independently

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to get the information within each month to toggle with the click of the button independently, and have the text of the button change based on if the information is shown or not. What am I doing wrong? The CSS for the page is stored in a separate document

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>JavaJam Coffee House</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="javajam.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js">
    </script>
    <![endif]-->
    <script src="http:ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".toggle_container").show(); 
            $("button").click(function(){
            $(this).toggleClass("active").next().slideToggle("fast");

                if ($.trim($(this).text()) === 'Hide') {
                    $(this).text('Show More');
                } else {
                    $(this).text('Hide');        
                }

                return false; 
        });
        $("a[href='" + window.location.hash + "']").parent(".reveal").click();
        });

    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
    <header>
        <h1>JavaJam Coffee Class</h1>
    </header>

    <nav>

        <ul>

            <li><a href="index.html"> Home </a></li>
            <li><a href="menu.html"> Menu </a></li>
            <li><a href="music.html"> Music</a></li>
            <li><a href="jobs.html"> Jobs</a></li>

        </ul>

    </nav>

    <main>
        <p>
        The first Friday night each month at JavaJam is a special night. Join us from
        8pm to 11pm for some music you won&rsquo;t want to miss!
        </p>

        <h2>January</h2>
        <div class="toggle_container">
            <p>
                <p class="details">
                <a href="images/melanie.jpg">
                <img src="images/melaniethumb.jpg" height="80" width="80" alt="Melanie Morris thumbnail" class="floatleft">
                </a>
                Melanie Morris entertains with her melodic folk style. Check out 
                the podcast! CDs are now available.
            </p>
            <button>Hide </button>
        </div>      

        <h2>February</h2>
        <div class="toggle_container">
            <p>
                <p class="details">
                <a href="images/greg.jpg">
                <img src="images/gregthumb.jpg" height="80" width="80" alt="Tahoe Greg thumbnail" class="floatleft">
                </a>
                Tahoe Greg&rsquo;s back from his tour. New songs. New stories. CDs are now available.
            </p>
            <button>Hide </button>
        </div>      

    </main>

    <footer>
        Copyright &copy; JavaJam Coffee House
        <br>
        <a href="mailto:jonathan@smith.com">jonathan@smith.com</a>
    </footer>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

are you looking for this?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
            $(".toggle_container").show(); 
            $("button").click(function(){
            $(this).toggleClass("active").prev().slideToggle("fast");

                if ($.trim($(this).text()) === 'Hide') {
                    $(this).text('Show More');
                } else {
                    $(this).text('Hide');        
                }

                return false; 
        });
        $("a[href='" + window.location.hash + "']").parent(".reveal").click();
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
    <header>
        <h1>JavaJam Coffee Class</h1>
    </header>

    <nav>

        <ul>

            <li><a href="index.html"> Home </a></li>
            <li><a href="menu.html"> Menu </a></li>
            <li><a href="music.html"> Music</a></li>
            <li><a href="jobs.html"> Jobs</a></li>

        </ul>

    </nav>

    <main>
        <p>
        The first Friday night each month at JavaJam is a special night. Join us from
        8pm to 11pm for some music you won&rsquo;t want to miss!
        </p>

        <h2>January</h2>
        <div class="toggle_container">
            <p>
                <p class="details">
                <a href="images/melanie.jpg">
                <img src="images/melaniethumb.jpg" height="80" width="80" alt="Melanie Morris thumbnail" class="floatleft">
                </a>
                Melanie Morris entertains with her melodic folk style. Check out 
                the podcast! CDs are now available.
            </p>
            <button>Hide </button>
        </div>      

        <h2>February</h2>
        <div class="toggle_container">
            <p>
                <p class="details">
                <a href="images/greg.jpg">
                <img src="images/gregthumb.jpg" height="80" width="80" alt="Tahoe Greg thumbnail" class="floatleft">
                </a>
                Tahoe Greg&rsquo;s back from his tour. New songs. New stories. CDs are now available.
            </p>
            <button>Hide </button>
        </div>      

    </main>

    <footer>
        Copyright &copy; JavaJam Coffee House
        <br>
        <a href="mailto:jonathan@smith.com">jonathan@smith.com</a>
    </footer>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `.details` element is the previous sibling of the clicked button so use `.prev()` instead of `.next()`.

Also in your html there is an extra `p` element before `p.details` element, remove it.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".toggle_container").show();
    $("button").click(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass("active").prev().slideToggle("fast");

        if ($.trim($(this).text()) === 'Hide') {
            $(this).text('Show More');
        } else {
            $(this).text('Hide');
        }

        return false;
    });
    $("a[href='" + window.location.hash + "']").parent(".reveal").click();
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/m0erwtdx/)